# How can I access propertyfile outside the method?

Tags: java, selenium

I have created a PropertyFile method and loaded the file there. I want to access this in another method. How can I do it?

```
public class Login {


void PropertyFile() throws IOException{
Properties objprop = new Properties();
FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("C:\\ejagruti-Automation\\mm_finsys\\ejagruti\\src\\test\\resources")+"\\xpath.properties");
objprop.load(objfile);
}
//When user opens the "firefox" browser
void OpenBrowser(String browsername) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",config.getParameterValue("chrome_driver_exe_path_32bit"));
    config.driver=new ChromeDriver();
}
Login loginpage = null;
public void EnterUserName(String username){
    config.driver.findElement(By.xpath(objprop.getProperty("objUserName"))).sendKeys("dummycfo");

}
```

I get an error at  config.driver.findElement(By.xpath(**objprop**.getProperty....

Answer (score 0):

If you will need property file again move `objprop` to be a field (see below) and call `PropertyFile()` method before `EnterUserName()`

```
public class Login {
Properties objprop;

void PropertyFile() throws IOException{
    objprop = new Properties();
```

If you need it once, other option is to get property file returned in `PropertyFile()`

```
  Properties PropertyFile() throws IOException{
   Properties objprop = new Properties();
   FileInputStream objfile = new 
   FileInputStream(System.getProperty("C:\\ejagruti-Automation\\mm_finsys\\ejagruti\\src\\test\\resources")+"\\xpath.properties");
   objprop.load(objfile);
   return objprop;
 }

 public void EnterUserName(String username){
  objprop = PropertyFile();
  config.driver.findElement(By.xpath(objprop
```

Method (except constructors) names should start with lower case letter to differentiate from class, e.g. change `EnterUserName()` to `enterUserName()`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a main or driver method, obtain the properties from `propertyFile()` method and store it in a local variable. Pass this properties as a parameter to `enterUserName()` method.

```
public void yourMainOrDriverMethod()
{
    Properties objprop = propertyFile();
    enterUserName(username, objprop);
}

public void enterUserName(String username, Properties objprop){
   //Your code
}
```

This will make `enterUserName()` method testable with any properties.